# share internet using my laptop as proxy

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, proxy, openvpn

I use openvpn from my laptop to tunnel to internet and internet comes through my home wifi router. This router inturn is connected to WAN. All my devices are connected to this home wifi router.

Note: I have to use openvpn to access internet resources. I cant access directly.

Now I would like to share my laptop internet with my other devices as well.
I could install openvpn on my other android devices and share the .ovpn file and continue using the internet but problem is .ovpn expires after couple of days and I have to renew it. I don't want to take up the hassle of renewing .ovpn to each devices (I know its minuscule but still).

I looked around and found installing a proxy server could be my solution. so, all my devices connect to my laptop and there is no need to install openvpn and .ovpn on each devices. keeps it centralized and neat for my trivial needs.

are there any other better solution that I can leverage?

Comment: Yes! Run openvpn at the router level. Let the router share the VPN subnet to all the devices.

Comment: I don't think if my router D-link DIR 600M supports tunneling.

Comment: https://wikidevi.com/wiki/List_of_DD-WRT_firmware_supported_devices

Comment: unfortunately, DD-WRT doesn't support my router

Comment: https://m.ebay.com/itm/Linksys-WRT160N-4-Port-10-100-Wireless-N-Router-with-DD-WRT/112798048099?epid=111162623&hash=item1a43499f63:g:vJoAAOSwkrFaeKzS

Comment: It doesn't have to be a crazy model for what you are trying to do. They go for pennies on eBay. Just keep your eye out